# Is there a clever Null Pointer Checker Utility Class for ActionScript/Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Problem involves checking if variables are null before calling methods or variables within them:

```
if(order && order.reference && order.reference.quote)
{
   var length:int = order.reference.quote.findLength();
}
```

Would'nt it be great to have a function that could be used with any objects that checks for null pointers up to the last object variable:

i.e.

```
     // This would check first if order, then order.reference, then order.reference.quote      
    //was null
    if(NullUtil.notNull(order.reference.quote))
    {
        .....
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's just a simple try/catch in a utility class that's needed? Still, I havn't seen one being used yet

Comment: Interesting… Are there any other languages that have a construct like this ?

Comment: Here is an article I found for an approach in C# http://blog.getpaint.net/2008/12/06/a-fluent-approach-to-c-parameter-validation/

Answer (score 3):

Some other languages use an existential accessor operator like `?.` (see [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) )

If you weren't too worried about performance, you could do something like:

```
function notNull(object:*, properties:String):Boolean
{
    if (object == null) return false;
    var props:Array = properties.split(".")
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < props.length; i++)
    {
        if(object[props[i]] == null) return false;
        object = object[props[i]]
    }

    return true;
}
```

And then use it with: `notNull(order, "reference.quote");`

But that is not very pretty, but you could probably clean it up a *bit* with some `Proxy` magic.

For example, consider the following code:

```
import flash.utils.Proxy;
import flash.utils.flash_proxy;

dynamic class Existential extends Proxy {

    private var _object:*;


    public function Existential(object:*) {
        _object = object;
    }

    flash_proxy override function getProperty(name:*):* {
        var object:* = _object;

        if (object == null) return null;

        var props:Array = name.toString().split("$");

        for(var i:uint = 0; i < props.length; i++)
        {
            if(object[props[i]] == null) return null;
            object = object[props[i]]
        }

        return object;
    }
}
```

You could then use it to wrap other objects and access them using `$` rather than `.` as a make-shift existential getter.

```
    obj = {};
    eObj = new Existential(obj);
    eObj.what$is$this // null

    obj = { what: { "is":  { "this": 1 } } } ;
    eObj = new Existential(obj);
    eObj.what$is$this  // 1
```

But I imagine that the performance would be horrenous, and I wouldn't want to use it for any performance critical production code. But it might give you some ideas.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Performance is a big deal, so would have to be taken into consideration!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `try..catch`.

```
try
{
   length = order.reference.quote.findLength();
}
catch(e:ReferenceError){}
```

Pros:

- Avoids conditionals in your code.
- The same code works for any object and any depth.

Cons:

- Doesn't do *exactly* the same thing as your code. For example, if one of the properties was a getter that threw a ReferenceError, your code would throw the error, but this code would not.
- Using `try..catch` introduces some overhead.
- Slightly harder to debug.